# I am looking to create a OCR for Arabic language. How do i get started?

Tags: python, nlp, ocr

Pretty much the title. Using NLP, i want something that can extract text from images. I am new to this and don't know where to start and how to go about it. Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to create it or use known API?
There is two good known options, Google vision or tesseract.
in tesseract the flag for Arabic is 'ara' -> https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata_best/master/ara.traineddata.
In Google vision is languageHints = 'ar'